# Record Duplication: Access 2003, VBA. Server Filter stuck

Tags: filter, duplicates, records

I have had a question that I actually know the answer to but wanted to put it out there for anyone else who may be struggling with it since I have not found an answer on the internet but pieced it together myself.  For the sake of saving someone else the trouble.  When your users get the same record every time they click on a different record, in Access 2003, it is most likely because when you saved in design mode it also saved the server filter property to whatever record it filtered to.  Then when you send it live it is stuck that way.  I will provide the answer to this problem below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work on every "Event" so the best thing to do is to put this code in whatever button you use to open whatever form is getting it's ServerFilter property stuck or duplicating the same record each time. Again, insert this code in the button that opens your form with the problem and do it before the "OpenForm" function calls the form you need: 'Close the supplied Form. Just in case it is open DoCmd.Close acForm, "Orders" 'ReOpen the supplied Form but in Design View. DoCmd.OpenForm "Orders", acDesign

```
Public Sub Whatever()
On Error GoTo LiveError

  'Set all filters to ""
  Forms![Orders].Filter = ""
  Forms![Orders].ServerFilter = ""

  'Save the form in design view
  DoCmd.Save acForm, "Orders"

  'Close the supplied Form.
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "Orders"

  'This is where your Open Form function would go, to open whatever form you need 
  'as usual.  The only difference now is that all pre-saved filters will be gone 
  'before you apply the new filter.

  Exit Sub

LiveError:
  'This is so that when it goes live it doesn't error out since it can't open 
  'in design mode on the live server.

  'Continue opening whatever form you planned on before.  For example:

  Call OpenOrderForm(Forms![FORMNAME]![FILTERCRITERIA])
End Sub
```